# Intersperse items of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array similar to this:

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2],
               [3, 4]],
              [[5, 6],
               [7, 8]],
              [[9, 10],
               [11, 12]]])
```

What I'd like to do is intersperse each 2D array contained inside the outer array to produce this result:

```
t = np.array([[[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10]],
              [[3, 4], [7, 8], [11, 12]]])
```

I could do this in Python like this, but I'm hoping there's a more efficient, numpy version:

```
t = np.empty((a.shape[1], a.shape[0], a.shape[2]), a.dtype)
for i, x in np.ndenumerate(a):
   t[i[1], i[0], i[2]] = x
```

Comment: isn't it just the transpose of the matrix? (if you consider the two-tuple as one element

Comment: I don't think so. I couldn't get it to work using transpose

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh I just tried again with `a.transpose((1, 0, 2))` and it worked... Odd that I didn't spot that earlier. Anyway, thanks for mentioning it. Feel free to post an answer and I'll mark as accepted

Comment: It's okay if you mark any of the answers already here as accepted. I don't want to add an redundant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @UdayrajDeshmukh said, you can use the `transpose` method (which, despite the name that evokes the "transpose" operator in linear algebra, is better understood as "permuting the axes"):

```
>>> t = a.transpose(1, 0, 2)
>>> t
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 5,  6],
        [ 9, 10]],

       [[ 3,  4],
        [ 7,  8],
        [11, 12]]])
```

The newly created object `t` is a shallow array looking into `a`'s data with a different permutation of indices.  To replicate your own example, you need to `copy` it, e.g. `t = a.transpose(1, 0, 2).copy()`

Answer (score 1):

Try the `transpose` function. You simply change the first two axes.

```
t = np.transpose(a, axes=(1, 0, 2))
```